# Accessing server side functions using Express.js and EJS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm running a test app in Express.js using EJS as the templating engine. I'd like to access functions stored in a .js file to run server side and not client side. For instance if I have:

```
<%= console.log("I'm in the server console"); %>
```

the server catches the console output, and if I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> console.log("I'm in the client-side console"); </script>
```

Now if I have a function to output the same for the client side I can include it this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/clientSideCode.js"> clientSideOutput(); </script>
```

But how do I include a file and its functions that way so EJS can execute server side code? It appears that the `public` folder in express is just for client side code.

Comment: Look at helper functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can create helper functions that your templates can access via `app.locals`:

- http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals

Comment: I'm not sure that's exactly what I'm looking for. Does that just expose an object or a whole function. Let's day I have a function named `createFile` that would create a file on the server after someone clicks on a link, how would I do that?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a route. To create a file on the server when someone clicks a link, you'll want to use ajax (or a POST to a renderable page) and a route on the server that can create files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [node.js](http://nodejs.org) and [Socket.IO](http://socket.io) to emit real time events between client and server.  For instance the client would do something like:

```
<script>window onload = function() {

socket.emit('request_customer_list', { state: "tx" });

socket.on('receive_customer_list', function(data) {
$.each(data.customer_list, function(key, value) {

  socket.set(key, value); // store the customer data and then print it later
});

});}
```

On your server you can have a routine to load the customer list and send it back in similar format:

```
socket.on('connection')
  socket.on('request_customer_list', function(data){
   state = data.state;
   var customer_list;
   // pretend i loaded a list of customers from whatever source right here
   socket.emit('receive_customer_list', {customer_list: customer_list});
)} )};
```

Answer (score 0):

The helper function is definitely the way to go, as @hunterloftis said, and then access it via EJS. To expand on his answer:

app.js:

```js
clientSideOutput() {
    // Your code
}

const app = express()

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.locals.clientSideOutput= clientSideOutput
```

Yout template.ejs file:

```html
<div>
    Some text, then <%= clientSideOutput() %>
</div>
```